# Cocos2d frame rate dropping

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, frame-rate, kobold2d

I am really close to completing my cocos2d project and I have a problem, the frame rate keeps dropping in certain parts of my game. I have tried to look at the code that is being executed at the time that the fps drops but the problem with that is it doesn't always drop at the same point. So my question is how can I analyze my code and see where and why the frame rate is dropping? I am using cocos2d v1.1.0-beta2b

Comment: Is there by chance a tutorial that would show how to do such a thing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665654/i-need-instruments-tutorial ;)